# find the limit of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set of finite measure. Find $$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{m(E\cap[x,x+h])}{h}$$.
 It seems to me that this limit is the indicator function over E, if we consider it into two cases: x in E and x not in E.
In the case when x is in E, I want to have the fraction equal to 1 when h is sufficiently small, but I got stuck.
Please help me, thank you

Comment: Isn't it basically Lebesgue's density theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a direct application of [Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem): 
$$
\frac{m(E\cap[x,x+h])}{h}=\frac1h\,\int_{[x,x+h]}\,1_E\to 1_E\,\ \ \ \ \text{ a.e.}
$$